# I cannot break out of this loop even if I type y or n. What did I do wrong in this Python code?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    if ans != 'y' or ans != 'n':
        ans = input("Enter (y/n): ").lower()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Maybe you want `and` instead of `or` since as it is the condition is *always* True.

Comment: If you enter 'n', `ans != 'y'` is true. If you enter 'y', `ans != 'n'` is true. Every input is not y *or* not n.

Comment: I edited this so it displayed as code. You do that by indenting everything four spaces. If you are unhappy with the edit, you can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `or` operator. Thus, if `ans` is `'y'`, it is `!= 'n'`, and vice versa, so it continues with the loop anyways. Instead, use `and`:

```py
while True:
    if ans != 'y' and ans != 'n':
        ans = input("Enter (y/n): ").lower()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: `if ans not in ['y', 'n']` is a bit nicer.